# Choosing the maximum out of three sequentially arriving random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I'm working on this problem. Could you please check if I did it correctly?

> I first draw $X\sim \operatorname{unif}(0,1)$. I can accept it as my
> winnings or reject it. If I reject, I can draw $Y\sim
> \operatorname{unif}(0,1)$, assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
> I then can choose accept or reject it. If I reject it, I can draw
> another $Z\sim \operatorname{unif}(0,1)$ (which is independent from
> $Y$) and I'm stuck with it. Come up with a strategy to maximize my
> winnings.

I do it backwards. Suppose I just rejected $X$ and I'm deciding on my threshold on accepting $Y$. Denote it by $k$. That is, I will accept if $Y > k$ or reject otherwise. Then my expected winnings would be $(1-k)\frac{(1-k)}{2} + k\frac{1}{2}$, the maximum of which is achieved at $k = 1/2$. The expected gain would be $\frac{5}{8}$. Using the same logic, suppose the threshold for accepting $X$ is $m$. Then I would maximize $(1-m)\frac{1-m}{2} + m \frac{5}{8}$. I then got $m=3/8$.

Therefore, my strategy is to accept $X$ if $X > 3/8$ and accept $Y$ if $Y > 1/2$.

**Update** Thanks to @lulu, I realized that I made an algebraic error. This is my new solution.

Suppose I just rejected $X$ and I'm deciding on my threshold on accepting $Y$. Denote it by $k$. That is, I will accept if $Y > k$ or reject otherwise. Then my expected winnings would be $(1-k)\frac{(1-k)}{2} + k\frac{1}{2}$, the maximum of which is achieved at $k = 1/2$. The expected gain would be $\frac{1}{4}$. Using the same logic, suppose the threshold for accepting $X$ is $m$. Then I would maximize $(1-m)\frac{1-m}{2} + m \frac{1}{4}$. I then got $m=3/4$.

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Not following.  Why would you take $\frac 38$ initially but demand more on the second trial?  Surely your standards must drop as you deplete your options.

Comment: Good point! Not sure what I missed.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I messed up the algebra. The expected gain at $Y$ should be $1/4$. Following my logic, I would get $3/4$ as my first cutoff.

Comment: I do not see $\frac 34$ as the cutoff for $X$.  If you use $\frac 12$ as the cutoff for $Y$ then the two step process is expected to pay out $\int_{.5}^1x\,dx +\frac 14=\frac 58$.  $X$ only needs to beat that.